# some series about :On some strange summation formulas by R. William Gosper

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions, trigonometric-series

I read the paper [On some strange summation formulas](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255987146) by R. William Gosper which includes
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\cos\big(\sqrt{k^{2}\pi^{2} -a^2})}{k^{2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\big({-\cosh(a)}+\frac{3}{a}\sinh(a)\big)$$
I was looking at the following series maple could sum. Any idea how to prove it, thanks. Define
$$S_1(a)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \cos \left(\sqrt{k^2\pi ^2-a}\right)}{\left(k^2+1\right)}$$
$$S_2(a)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \cos \left(\sqrt{k^2\pi ^2-a}\right)}{\left(k^2+1\right)^2}$$
Let $\beta=\sqrt{-a-\pi^2}.\,$ Are the following true?:

$$S_1(a)=\frac{1}{2} \big(\pi\,  \text{csch}(\pi ) \cos ( \beta)-\cosh \left(\sqrt{a}\right)\big)$$
$$S_2(a)=\frac{1}{4} \Big(\pi\, \text{csch}(\pi ) \cos ( \beta) \big[1+\pi  \coth (\pi )\big] -2 \cosh \left(\sqrt{a}\right)-\frac{\pi ^3 \text{csch}(\pi ) \sin ( \beta)}{ \beta}\Big)$$

Comment: The paper was just a list of equations, with no derivations?

Comment: Can you please give the equation numbers of these formulas? Or at least give the page numbers where they appear in the paper.  That would help.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi  Matthew Conroy in the page 251 formula 3.5 you find formulas very similar at the above.

Comment: @pjs36:I think what the OP meant was that based on one Gosper formula in the paper cited, the OP found two similar ones experimentally using Maple and wishes to know if it can be proved rigorously. I've improved his post, in format and grammar, to reflect this. (I believe English isn't his first language.)

Comment: @antonioasis: I've edited your post to address the comments made by others. I am correct with regards to your intent, right? Namely that you found these two formulas, and wishes a proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$S_{1}\left(a\right)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\cos\left(\sqrt{k^{2}\pi^{2}-a}\right)}{k^{2}+1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\cos\left(\sqrt{k^{2}\pi^{2}-a}\right)}{k^{2}+1}-\frac{\cosh\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}{2}
 $$ and now we can apply this well [known summation formula](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf) $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(-1\right)^{n}f\left(n\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{residues of }\pi\csc\left(\pi z\right)f(z)\textrm{ at }f\left(z\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\} 
 $$ and so since we have poles at $z=\pm i
 $ we have that $$S_{1}\left(a\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi\cosh\left(\sqrt{a+\pi^{2}}\right)\textrm{csch}\left(\pi\right)}{2}-\frac{\cosh\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}{2}}.
 $$ In the same spirit we can evaluate $S_{2}\left(a\right)$ and get $$S_{2}\left(a\right)=\color{blue}{-\frac{\pi\textrm{csch}\left(\pi\right)}{4}\left(\frac{\pi^{2}\sinh\left(\gamma\right)}{\gamma}-\cosh\left(\gamma\right)-\pi\cosh\left(\gamma\right)\coth\left(\pi\right)\right)-\frac{\cosh\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}{2}}.$$
where $\gamma=\sqrt{a+\pi^{2}}$.

Comment: Lemma 5.2 in that paper doesn't help explain why $\oint_{C_{N}} \frac{\pi \csc(\pi z)\cos \left(\sqrt{\pi^{2}z^{2}-a} \right)}{z^{2}+1} \, dz $ vanishes as $N \to \infty$. What's important here is that $\left| \csc(\pi z) \cos \left(\sqrt{\pi^{2}z^{2}-a} \right) \right| \sim 1 $ as $\text{Im}(z) \to \pm \infty$. If the coefficient of the $z^{2}$ term were, say, $2 \pi^{2}$, then the contour integral would most likely not vanish since $\left| \csc(\pi z) \cos \left(\sqrt{2\pi^{2}z^{2}-a} \right) \right| $ grows exponentially as $\text{Im}(z) \to \pm \infty%$.

Comment: @RandomVariable You're absolutely right, I linked that paper but I read it time ago :D thank you for this important observation.